# Indicating list item is pressed

Tags: gui-design, touch-screen, mobile-application

What would be the most conventional way in showing that an item has been pressed in the list below... that would fit into my current design?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "selected"? This looks like a navigation menu, ie. selecting something should present the user with the view for what she selected?

Comment: @AndroidHustle - yes, as in the user presses it

Comment: Ohh, so you want input on a press state for the list items? If so I think the question could do with some editing since the answers you're received are for two different questions.

Comment: @AndroidHustle - I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible options:

> **New In**
>   0/157 styles
>
> **Accessories**
>   **5/96 styles**

or

> **New In**
>   157 styles
>
> **Accessories**
>   96 styles (**5** selected)

I'd prefer the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do reverse design for the selected menu. Make the background dark and change the texts in white. Hat background should be white and Hat need to be the same dark color as the background color. Hope it will help you.